# Make a command in Discordjs that only executes if the member is admin

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command, bots

I want to make one command only for admins.

```
//comando nick
        if(comando === 'nick'){
            if (message.author.permissions.has(!Permissions.STAGE_MODERATOR)) return message.reply('No Perms!');
            else{
                if(args == ''){
                    message.channel.send(`my message`);
                }
                else{
                    message.guild.members.cache.get(client.user.id).setNickname(`${args}`);
                    message.channel.send(`my message`);
                }
            }
        }
```

but i'm having this issue:

```
if (message.author.permissions.has(!Permissions.STAGE_MODERATOR)) return message.reply('No Perms!');

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'has')
```

I taken this code in Discord Js docs, but isn't working

Comment: Can you explain "it doesn't work"? What is it doing now and are there any errors? Please update the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`permissions` doesn't exist on type [`User`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) which is what [`Message#author`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author) returns. Use [`Message#member`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member) which returns a [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)

```js
if (message.member.permissions.has(!Permissions.STAGE_MODERATOR)) return message.reply('No Perms!')
```

Also note that you are using the logical NOT operator (`!`) wrong. Put it at the start of the `if` statement rather than as the permission (`!Permissions.STAGE_MODERATOR` is `false`)

```js
if (!message.member.permissions.has(Permissions.STAGE_MODERATOR)) return message.reply('No Perms!')
```